# "I suspect he will come" vs. "I suspect he might come"

Tags: word-choice, modal-verbs

Which of the 2 sentences is correct ?

> 1. I suspect that he will come here.
> 2. I suspect that he might come here.

As we have already used*'suspect*, is it wrong to use *might* again? (as using 2 words that express possibility/doubt will create an unnecessary double effect).

Answer (score 4):

Both are correct in English, though the second is somewhat redundant. The second construction shows less certainty. A native speaker would probably use the first if they were 90% sure, and the second if they were 60% sure.

Answer (score -2):

Yes it will make the sentence superfluous. So Don't use might.

Answer (score -2):

Both could be used and would be understood. 
But, based on sequence of time, the second one is gramaticcaly incorrect and the correct form is "I suspect that he might come here.".
using "might" would make sense if the main verb were in the past, thus "I suspected that he might come here.".

I give you some examples:

I think the stores are open. ---> (an hour later and having seen that they are cnot open) oh, I thought the stores were open.
I thik the stored will be open. ---> (an hour later and having seen that they are cnot open) oh, I thought the stores would be open.